How am I supposed to earn reputation points if I don't know enough to answer anything? Right now, I can't even upvote!
Seems like a glitch in the matrix to me.

I'm just trying to "upvote," I'm not sure why I can't upvote the answer that helped me the most.

One assumes you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

When you are able to vote up/down, you are welcome to go back and upvote posts that helped you.

since you don't know enough right now, reputation can be gained just as easily by asking good questions. Start by reading [ask]

Everyone starts the same, you have to have patience and in the mean time read all the rules whenever you can and be courteous. If you really want it it will happen eventually.
